# Passing multiples parameters to sql cursor output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a snippet of my SQL cursor, which works fine. But I now want to pass multiple parameters to `@sql`.

See the comment in the 2nd code snippet. I've googled, but I can't seem to find the answer to this.

```
set @sql = N' use TESTDOMAINDATABASE' + convert(nvarchar, @domainID) + @NewLineChar  +
           N' select @subDomain = (select subDomain from tblDomains (nolock))'

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@subDomain nvarchar(500) output', @subDomain output

print 'subDomain is ' + @subDomain + ' and the domainID is ' + convert(nvarchar,@domainID)
```

But let's say I wanted another column from `tblDomains` (say `domainName`).

How would I update the above statement?

```
set @sql = N' use TESTDOMAINDATABASE' + convert(nvarchar, @domainID) + @NewLineChar  +
           N' select @subDomain = (select subDomain from tblDomains (nolock))' + @NewLineChar  + 
           N'select @domainName = (select domainName from tblDomains(nolock))'

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@subDomain nvarchar(500) output', @subDomain output /* How do I pass multiple paramaters here ? */
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@domainName nvarchar(500) output', @domainName output /*Adding a 2nd line does not do the trick - results in an error that I must declare the scalar variable @domainName */

print 'subDomain is ' + @subDomain + ' and the domainID is ' + convert(nvarchar,@domainID) + ' +  and the domain name is ' @domainName'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this? Is there only one row in each database's tblDomains table?

```
set @sql = N' use TESTDOMAINDATABASE' + convert(nvarchar, @domainID) + @NewLineChar  +
           N' select @subDomain = subDomain, @domainName = domainName 
              from tblDomains (nolock);'

execute sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@subDomain nvarchar(500) output, @domainName nvarchar(500) output', 
    @subDomain output, @domainName output;

print 'subDomain is ' + @subDomain + ' and the domainID is ' + convert(nvarchar,@domainID)
```

Comment: Yes, each database's tblDomains table contains just 1 row. Very nice! Thanks again, Aaron.

Comment: You should considering storing that data centrally. You can always create a view in each database that pulls that database's row from the central view (identified by DB_NAME()).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple comma-separated parameters into sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @x nvarchar(25)
DECLARE @y nvarchar(25)

SET @sql = N'SELECT @x = ''hello'', @y = ''world'''

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@x nvarchar(25) output, @y nvarchar(25) output'
       ,@x output
       ,@y output

PRINT @x + ' ' + @y
```